# TIME_TICK System Broadcast not responds

Tags: java, android, time, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to utilize TIME_TICK broadcast receiver in my Alarm clock app and I face interesting issue. I register Broadcast receiver for mentioned system broadcast in foreground service and when I turn screen off broadcasts aren't received regularly or they don't come at all. have you any idea why this happens ?

eg. for time from 00:04 to 00:15

**00:04**

**00:06**

**00:07**

**00:08**

**00:09**

**00:10**

**00:11**

**00:15**

regards,
Adam

Comment: When the screen is off, it goes into Doze mode to save battery life.  In Doze, all broadcasts are delayed and processed in batches periodically, to save battery power.

Comment: Great, straightforward ansewr, thank you. Is there a way to utilize broadcast receiver in my case or I should look for AlarmManager ?

Answer (score 0):

For others facing same problem, I resolved it by utilizing AlarmManager which is well described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) . AlarmManager in my case fires up service which plays ringtone.

Regards,
Adam